# XML END OF FILE

Tags: android, xml

I am a beginner at android studio and I have a problem here on the XML file
the log is saying that there are two errors: `valid xml document must have a root tag` and `XML unexpected end of file`.

Here is a screenshot of android studio:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"/>

<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>ROOT</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>id</key>
                <string>2034</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Please need your help, Thank you!

Comment: Remove the DOCTYPE, maybe. What is plist doing in the android codebase? It's an iOS thing, no?

Comment: Does my answer solve your issue or are you still having problems?

Answer (score 0):

It’s because of the `/` at the end of the DOCTYPE declaration...

[image]

The DOCTYPE declaration is not an element so it doesn’t need to close (self closing or otherwise). [See here](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-doctypedecl) for more details.

Here's what your DOCTYPE declaration should look like after the `/` is removed...

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
```